# Windows 10 Wifi Limited Connection - Wi-FI doesn't have a valid IP configuration

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

Wifi was working via router in my house. Took it round to my friends house and it says Limited Connection.

Wireless network adaptor is **Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4** and current driver is 10.0.0.62. I tried updating (via GUI) this but it says I have the latest driver.

If I run Windows Network Diagnostics, it attempts to reset the wireless adaptor, and results in the following problem:

```
Wf-Fi doesn't have a valid IP configuration - Not Fixed
```

Running `ipconfig /release` prints:

```
An error occurred while releasing interface Wi-Fi : The system cannot find the file specified
```

I am finding that the problem is intermittent. I have just restarted the computer when it wasn't working and now the Wi-Fi connection is working.

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the issue? Please edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: Usually when you get the "Limited Connection" means that the wifi on your laptop is connected, but unable to reach the internet. Sometimes this happens and you are still are able to connect to the internet, if so this message will go away. Let us know if you are getting a connection at your friend's house, able to access the internet.

Comment: @FastEthernet I have updated the question with what I have tried.

Comment: @GeekyDaddy unfortunately not able to reach the internet in this case.

Comment: There is not enough information to diagnose this problem. You can get 'limited connection' when your IP address is wrong for the network you are on. This can happen for various reasons including bad decryption of the wifi or bad acquisition of a valid IP.

Answer (score 8):

Reset your TCP/IP:

1. Press your **Windows-Key**
2. type **cmd** into the `search programs and files` field
3. right-click the result and **run as administrator**
4. in the following window type first: **netsh winsock reset** followed by pressing return - you will be told that you have to restart your computer; ignore it for the moment
5. type **netsh int ip reset** followed by pressing return
6. close the cmd window and reboot

If you had a static IP you would need to set it again.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Could you explain why I need to reset winsock? In your experience has this fixed issue or will I need to continue to input the command?

Comment: The winsock is optional, however I would reset it just to make sure everything is working fine afterwards. Your TCP/IP will be reset by netsh int ip reset

Comment: Just worked perfectly for me! Windows 10 Professional Dell XPS 15 (2015)

Comment: When doing "netsh int ip reset" I got an "access denied" error, yet after the reboot the issue was fixed!  Thank you!